# Export excel in Lightning relationship field values shows undefined

Tags: lightning-aura-components

Setting the Attribute here:

```
<aura:attribute name="exportData" type="Object" />  <!-- values are setting here -->
<ui:button class="slds-button slds-button_neutral" press="{!c.downloadCsv}" label="Export CSV" />
```

Js side Logic:

```
downloadCsv : function(component,event,helper){
    // get the Records [contact] list from 'ListOfContact' attribute 
    var stockData = component.get("v.exportData");
    console.log('stock data@@',JSON.stringify(stockData));
    // call the helper function which "return" the CSV data as a String   
    var csv = helper.convertArrayOfObjectsToCSV(component,stockData);   
     if (csv == null){return;} 
    // ####--code for create a temp. <a> html tag [link tag] for download the CSV file--####     
     var hiddenElement = document.createElement('a');
      hiddenElement.href = 'data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURI(csv);
      hiddenElement.target = '_self'; // 
      hiddenElement.download = 'ExportData.csv';  // CSV file Name* you can change it.[only name not .csv] 
      document.body.appendChild(hiddenElement); // Required for FireFox browser
      hiddenElement.click(); // using click() js function to download csv file
    }
```

helper:

```
   convertArrayOfObjectsToCSV : function(component,objectRecords){
    // declare variables
    var csvStringResult, counter, keys, columnDivider, lineDivider;

    // check if "objectRecords" parameter is null, then return from function
    if (objectRecords == null || !objectRecords.length) {
        return null;
     }
    // store ,[comma] in columnDivider variabel for sparate CSV values and 
    // for start next line use '\n' [new line] in lineDivider varaible  
    columnDivider = ',';
    lineDivider =  '\n';
    // in the keys valirable store fields API Names as a key 
    // this labels use in CSV file header  
    keys = ['Name','PrimaryId__c','PrimaryIdType__c','RequestType__c','CreatedBy.Name','ConsolidatedStatus__c','CreatedDate','DueDate__c','GDPRRequestSubscriberStatuses__r.SecondaryIdSnapshot__c'];
    csvStringResult = '';
    csvStringResult += ['Transaction Id','Primary ID','Primary ID Type','FLAG','Submitted By','Status','Creation Date','Due Date','Secondary Id'];
    //csvStringResult += keys.join(columnDivider);
    csvStringResult += lineDivider;

    for(var i=0; i < objectRecords.length; i++){   
        counter = 0;

         for(var sTempkey in keys) {
            var skey = keys[sTempkey] ;  

          // add , [comma] after every String value,. [except first]
              if(counter > 0){ 
                  csvStringResult += columnDivider; 
               }   

           csvStringResult += '"'+ objectRecords[i][skey]+'"'; 

           counter++;

        } // inner for loop close 
         csvStringResult += lineDivider;
      }// outer main for loop close 

   // return the CSV formate String 
    return csvStringResult;        
}
```

Apex class:

```
 @AuraEnabled
public static List<Object> gdprCompleteRecords(){
    return [SELECT ID,(SELECT ID,SecondaryIdSnapshot__c FROM GDPRRequestSubscriberStatuses__r),Name,PrimaryId__c,PrimaryIdType__c,RequestType__c,createdBy.Name,ConsolidatedStatus__c,CreatedDate,DueDate__c FROM GDPRRequest__c];
}
```

Relationship fields are showing undefined values:

- createdBy.Name
- GDPRRequestSubscriberStatuses__r.SecondaryIdSnapshot__c

Receiving following json format in javascript:

```
 [
 {
"Id": "a7U0m0000000J0UEAU",
"Name": "Request-000480",
"PrimaryId__c": "test@gmail.com",
"PrimaryIdType__c": "Email",
"RequestType__c": "SAR-TIER2",
"CreatedById": "0050m0000034uICAAY",
"ConsolidatedStatus__c": "2 New",
"CreatedDate": "2020-03-04T05:58:27.000Z",
"DueDate__c": "2020-04-03",
"GDPRRequestSubscriberStatuses__r": [
  {
    "GDPRRequest__c": "a7U0m0000000J0UEAU",
    "Id": "a7T0m000000DTnWEAW"
  },
  {
    "GDPRRequest__c": "a7U0m0000000J0UEAU",
    "Id": "a7T0m000000DTnXEAW"
  }
   ],
      "CreatedBy": {
      "Name": "Annappa PH",
      "Id": "0050m0000034uICAAY"
   }
   },
  {
"Id": "a7U0m0000000I6CEAU",
"Name": "Request-000351",
"PrimaryId__c": "test12345@gmail.com",
"PrimaryIdType__c": "Email",
"RequestType__c": "SAR-TIER2",
"CreatedById": "0050m0000034uICAAY",
"ConsolidatedStatus__c": "1 New",
"CreatedDate": "2020-02-19T04:11:18.000Z",
"DueDate__c": "2020-03-20",
"GDPRRequestSubscriberStatuses__r": [
  {
    "GDPRRequest__c": "a7U0m0000000I6CEAU",
    "Id": "a7T0m000000DT4MEAW",
    "SecondaryIdSnapshot__c": "OriginId - test12 , FacebookId - test13"
  }
],
"CreatedBy": {
  "Name": "Annappa PH",
  "Id": "0050m0000034uICAAY"
}
}
```

]

but in excel sheet createdBy.Name & GDPRRequestSubscriberStatuses__r.SecondaryIdSnapshot__c undefined.

createdby name issue got ressolved: but secondary id issue still remaining

added following code:

```
     for(var i=0; i < objectRecords.length; i++){   
        counter = 0;
        for(var sTempkey in keys) {
            var skey = keys[sTempkey] ;
           // alert('skey@'+skey);
           // add , [comma] after every String value,. [except first]
              if(counter > 0){ 
                  csvStringResult += columnDivider; 
               }   
            if(objectRecords[i][skey] != undefined){
                if(skey=='CreatedBy'){
                    csvStringResult += '"'+ objectRecords[i][skey].Name+'"';
                }if(skey=='GDPRRequestSubscriberStatuses__r'){
                    csvStringResult += '"'+ objectRecords[i][skey].SecondaryIdSnapshot__c+'"';
                }if(skey!='CreatedBy'&&skey!='GDPRRequestSubscriberStatuses__r')
                 csvStringResult += '"'+ objectRecords[i][skey]+'"';
              }
             else
             {
                 csvStringResult += '"'+ '' +'"';
             }
            counter++;

        } // inner for loop close 
         csvStringResult += lineDivider;
      }// outer main for loop close
```

screen shot: secondary id columns shows below:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't pass a relationship path as a key to an sObject represented as a dict, which is what you're doing here:

```
       csvStringResult += '"'+ objectRecords[i][skey]+'"';
```

`objectRecords[i]` does not contain the keys `CreatedBy.Name` or `GDPRRequestSubscriberStatuses__r.SecondaryIdSnapshot__c`. That's not how nested sObject data works.

Rather, `objectRecords[i]` will contain a key called `CreatedBy`, whose object value contains the key `Name`. `GDPRRequestSubscriberStatuses__r` will contain an array of objects, each of which (assuming a non-zero number of entries are present) will contain a `SecondaryIdSnapshot__c` key. This data structure parallels how relationship query results are represented in Apex and in the JSON returned by calls to the Salesforce REST API's query endpoint.

You'll need to write logic to decompose these relationship path strings and walk through the nested object data to obtain the values. For `GDPRRequestSubscriberStatuses__r`, you'll need to be prepared to handle multiple child records, since this is a one-to-many relationship.

Comment: yes. i got that. can you please explain me on this: For GDPRRequestSubscriberStatuses__r, you'll need to be prepared to handle multiple child records, since this is a one-to-many relationship. its really helpfu;

Comment: What specifically are you asking about? You are making a parent-child subquery, and any parent may have multiple child records.

Comment: that i got it. how i can display the child records related to the parents. in javascript.that i didnt get i properly and i have confused about logic.

Comment: I have no way to answer that. Your business requirements should tell you what data to display and how.

Comment: Let consider parent records has 2 child records. we display that child record information  like this.  request1[column 1],     second1 (child1) (new line here) second2(child2).  [column 2] . But i didnt get how to do this.

Comment: i got your point.but i didnt get this: You'll need to write logic to decompose these relationship path strings and walk through the nested object data to obtain the values. For GDPRRequestSubscriberStatuses__r, you'll need to be prepared to handle multiple child records, since this is a one-to-many relationship.

Comment: i have opened new question: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/296929/how-to-iterate-json-values-in-javscript-in-lightning